# Postgres: How to Backup & Restore a table

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I want to run an Update Query over a table, but before I do I want to ensure I can restore the table in case the Query goes bad. So what I thought would be a simple process has become difficult as the Restore doesn't work.

I am using PgAdmin3 and on my table I am right-clicking and selecting 'Backup'
In the File Options I am selecting Custom. I am not selecting any compression, Encoding or Role Names and in the Dump Options I am only selecting 'Sections/Data'. The Backup string looks liek this:

`pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password --format custom --section data --verbose --file "D:\TEMP\TableBackup.backup" --table "mytable" "myDatabase"`

I then move to immediately test this backup by Restoring it and select the Filename and Format of 'Custom or Tar' and no other Restore Options selected.

`pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "myDatabase" --no-password  --table myTable --schema mySchema --verbose "D:\TEMP\TableBackup.backup"`

And the following Error is returned:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
pg_restore: processing data for table "myTable"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2305; 0 18581 TABLE DATA myTable mySchema
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "myTable": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myTemplate_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (oid)=(618001) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY myTable, line 1
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for TABLE DATA myTable
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1
Process returned exit code 1.
```

What is the Duplicate Key?

How do I deal with this?

What is it about OID=618001?
I want the entire table restored including the OID's so why is this field erroring?
I would have thought it would just restore everything over the top?

Thanks in Advance
Daz

Comment: Run the `UPDATE` in a transaction and roll back if it "goes bad".

Comment: What does that mean, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the whole problem by running the `UPDATE` in an explicit transaction that you roll back if something is not right:

```
/* start a transaction */
START TRANSACTION;

/* run your UPDATE */
UPDATE ...

/*
 * Now check if your UPDATE did the right thing.
 * If it did, run COMMIT to complete the transaction.
 * If not, run ROLLBACK to undo everything that happened in the transaction.
 */
COMMIT;  -- or ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a copy of the data back into the table, while the old version is still there.  So you get a violation of the unique key constraint.  You would have to truncate away the old data before you restore the new data.  But you might have problems with foreign keys if you try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new table using the "like" keyword and copy all data.

create table "tableA_bkp" (like "tableA")
insert into "tableA_bkp" select * from "tableA"